# Reusing BodyHandler instance

Tags: vert.x

I'm trying to create something like

```kotlin
router.route("foo").handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024))
router.route("bar").handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024))
router.route("baz").handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024))
```

Would it be ok to call `BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024)` only once in the app, and reuse it all over the place I need it?

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, you should be able to share `BodyHandler` between multiple routes. In fact, it is usually shared by setting it on all routes, as was correctly pointed out in another answer.
You can [take a look at the code](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/impl/BodyHandlerImpl.java#L99) and see that it doesn't mutate anything internaly, so should be safe.

```java
var defaultBodyHandler = BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1000L);
router.route("foo").handler(defaultBodyHandler).handler((ctx) -> {});
router.route("bar").handler(defaultBodyHandler).handler((ctx) -> {});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, @alexey-soshin
Do you think there's significant overhead if I just set it for all the routes I have it, no matter if body is needed or not.

Comment: Usually in Vert.x apps, you set it for all handlers, unless you have a very specific reason. There is very little overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can re-use it. But it might make sense, according to what is provided in the question, to define a global BodyHandler:

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024*1024))
router.route("foo")...
router.route("bar")...
router.route("baz")...
```

Comment: Not all the routes need body handling. It was unclear by reading the docs if instances are to be created wherever required or can be re-used.